# neo4j -changing node properties

Tags: neo4j, social-networking, py2neo

I'm trying to make a social network and its my first web experience.
I'm using Neo4j database and py2neo module.
Now I want to find a node from my database and change some of it's properties.
I'm using the code below,and i can run it with no errors .but it doesn't change anything in my database and i have no idea why...
please help me if you can.

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph=Graph()
def edit_name(Uname,name):
person=graph.merge_one("Person","username",Uname)
person.cast(fname=name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast is for casting general Python objects to py2neo objects. For example, if you wanted to cast a Python dictionary to a py2neo Node object, you'd do:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node
graph = Graph()

d = {'name':'Nicole', 'age':24}
nicole = Node.cast('Person', d)
```

However, you still need to pass `nicole` to `Graph.create` to actually create the node in the database:

```
graph.create(nicole)
```

Then, if you later retrieve this node from the database with `Graph.merge_one` and want to update properties:

```
nicole = graph.merge_one('Person', 'name', 'Nicole')
nicole['hair'] = 'blonde'
```

Then you need to `push` those changes to the graph; `cast` is inappropriate for updating properties on something that is already a py2neo `Node` object:

```
nicole.push()
```

TL;DR:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()

def edit_username(old_name, new_name):
    person = graph.merge_one('Person', 'username', old_name)
    person['username'] = new_name
    person.push()
```

Answer (score 0):

`merge_one` will either return a matching node, or, if no matching node exists, create and return a new one. So, in your case, a matching node probably already exists.

Comment: yeah it exists. and when i return the node ,it returns correctly.
but "person.cast(fname=name)" doesn't work correctly